# Can ButtonMenu options be updated? - PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to change the dropdown menu of a ButtonMenu in PySimpleGui and running into some issues. I have this ButtonMenu defined.

```
gui.ButtonMenu('Bosses',menu_def=poh_menu_def,border_width=5,key='-SLAYER-')
```

and I have this later in the code.

```
window['-SLAYER-'].update(menu_def=new_menu_def)
```

I'm trying to change the options when the '-SLAYER-' menu is accessed by updating its menu_def, but this does not seem to be allowed.

```
TypeError: ButtonMenu.update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'menu_def'
```

I've tried substituting values for menu_def in the update call but unsurprisingly that threw the same error. Is there a way to update the options in a ButtonMenu?

Comment: Of course, it can be updated, but very complex, you need to update it by long tkinter code to do the job, so it cannot be done at this moment.

Comment: The argument is `menu_definition`, not `menu_def`.  The call reference has a list of the options for the update method. 
 https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#buttonmenu-element